# Git repositories on VS Solutions instead of Projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, git, version-control, project

Currently I use Git (with Git Extensions for Visual Studio) as version control system of my application.

My application consists of 4 projects in VS2010 inside one solutions and I have created 4 different git repositories. However, every time I want to commit my complete solution, I have to commit all 4 projects, one by one.

The commit option is only selectable when a project in Visual Studio is selected, but not when the complete solution is selected. Since I generally change 2 or 3 projects at a time, it would be easier if I could commit the solution instead of 4 individual projects (main reason is that I only have to add a description once for example). E.g. one of the projects is the unit tests project which typically changes when adding files in the other projects.

I couldn't find a way to have a single Git repository for a complete solution... is this possible or is there a reason why this is not possible, or a better alternative?

Comment: 4 different git repos for 4 different projects and you have to commit to all of them to save your changes in one? I'd say report a bug @ VS

Comment: Could you explain again why you think you have to commit all 4 projects (repositories, right?)? When you do commit, you should be in 1 of them and that commit should be about the project (repository) your are in only and has nothing to do with the other 3.

Comment: I noticed I work mostly in 1 but after that I change tests and sometimes I also touch the generic repository. When the total is working I want to commit the complete solution and mark it with a release number. It would seem logical to be able to commit on any level, not only at (MS VS) project level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I used some wrong directory because one of these projects somehow stores all information to the GIT database.

I still have to get rid of the other three, but I'm afraid I will lose history information so I leave it as it is now.